# Generate LUT from pre- and post-grade image

Tags: software, lut

Is there any way one could generate LUT by comparing the graded and ungraded variant of the same frame?

Let's say I have footage straight from the camera and I also have some of the clips already graded, but I don't have the project. This means I have no way of just extending the same basic grading to the other clips. But maybe some software could just take the graded and ungraded clip, compare them and generate LUT from that, no?

Answer (score 1):

One method would be *MatchGrade* in **Nuke** (available only in NukeX and Nuke Studio). It can calculate LUT/CDL from two inputs.

https://learn.foundry.com/nuke/content/reference_guide/color_nodes/matchgrade.html

Blackmagic Resolve has feature for automatic shot matching, but I don't know if you can export LUT from that.

Comment: MatchGrade in Nuke seems to have very good results, however the LUT file is .csp, is there any way to export more universal format?

Comment: You could go by the way of **GenerateLut** via **CMSTestPattern** -> **OCIOFileTransform** (using csp file generated from **MatchGrade**) -> **GenerateLut**. But I would go easier way using [LUTLab](http://opensource.mikrosimage.eu/ColorPipe-tools/LUTLab/)